# Drop keys from a dictionary based on a string value in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key

Why doesn't this work:
I have a dictionary inside dictionary

```
{'rrr-rrr/CCC-3/FFFF-1': {'ActiveSet': '0'},
'rrr-rrr/CCC-4/FFFF-1': {'ActiveSet': '1'},
...}
```

And I need to drop keys where CCC is 3 (CCC-3).
The way I've tried is this:

```
my_dict = {k: v 
           for k, v in my_dict.iteritems() 
           if k.split('/')[1].split('-')[1]!= 3
           }
```

And there is no error with this code, but nothing happens. I've tried also to make new key inside inner dict from that CCC number but that doesn't work too. 
Desired output:

```
{'rrr-rrr/CCC-4/FFFF-1': {'ActiveSet': '1'},
    ...}
```

Comment: Because `3` as part of your key is a string and not an integer so they're not equal... Try `!= '3'` instead...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jon Clements [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46156129/drop-keys-from-a-dictionary-based-on-a-string-value-in-python/46156203#comment79273945_46156129), you're comparing a string to an integer, so your `if` condition will never evaluate to true.

As a fix, I'd go with something more like:

```
val = 3
my_dict = {k : v 
           for k, v in my_dict.iteritems() 
           if 'CCC-{}'.format(val) not in k
         }
```

This way, you don't have to hardcode your split and indexing. Note that, if you have keys of the form `CCC-<number>` where the number is two or more digits, you'll need to match `CCC-{}/`, as Danil Speransky smartly observes in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46156309/4909087).

---

Note that the python 3 equivalent of `dict.iteritems` is `dict.items`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because you compare an integer and a string. Change it to `'3'`:

```
if k.split('/')[1].split('-')[1] != '3'
```

Or simpler:

```
if 'CCC-3/' not in k
```

I have added `/` to not exclude `CCC-32`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just search for your desired pattern in the key:

```
new_data = {a:b for a, b in d.items() if "CCC-3" not in a}
```